# copy() function doesn't work

Tags: php, copy, file-permissions

I have task to copy my file from a folder to the current one. But when I perform this I get the following error:

```
Warning:  copy(C:/wamp/www/dfms/) [function.copy]: failed to open stream:
Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\dfms\docShow.php on line 646
```

The code is given below

```
if (copy('images/uploads/'.$doclisting['docfile_name'], 'C:/wamp/www/dfms/'))
{
  echo "Pranav";
}
```

I also tried by using `chmod 0777` but still it gives me same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried adding the filename to the destination?

Like so:

```
if(copy('images/uploads/'.$doclisting['docfile_name'],'C:/wamp/www/dfms/'.$doclisting['docfile_name']))
  {
    echo "Pranav";
  }
```

Comment: Your welcome, this is common mistake because most people believe php would take the source filename for the destination. Would be great if you would approve the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You are on a windows server, which means that `chmod 0777` will probably not do much.

What you need to do is give Apache the permission to write to `C:/wamp/www/dfms/` -- doing so the windows way.

Not sure about a Windows server, but I'm guessing right-clicking on that directory, choosing Properties, findind some "permission" or "security" tab, and checking some checkbox that corresponds to "write" for the correct user should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

chmod 0777 is a unix command, I'd be curious how you successfully tried this on windows.

Check these file and directory access control. You should make sure that the webserver process/user has the rights to this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "allow_url_fopen = On" in your php.ini

The php.ini file is where you declare changes to your PHP settings. You can edit the existing php.ini, or create a new text file in any subdirectory and name it php.ini.